# Problema con imágenes en CakePHP 3 (Missing controller)

Tags: sql-server, imagen, cakephp

Tengo un problema con CakePHP 3, cuando el server me manda una imagen, me da un error dependiendo de como termine el formato (.JPG o .JPEG), lo que no tiene logica ya que son el mismo formato, aveces pasa con uno y aveces con el otro, que puedo hacer?

[image: eror de cakephp]

[image: la misma imagen funcionando con .JPEG]

(UPDATE): el problema era un pluggin de recorte de imagen que la recortaba despues de que se habia cargado en la base de datos, y al recortaba hacia el cambio entre jpg y jpeg.

Comment: Que sean el mismo formato no quiere decir nada: si tienen extensiones diferentes, son diferentes ficheros. Por ejemplo, puedes tener una página web `index.htm`, y si intentas ir a `index.html` el servidor te va a decir que no existe aunque tengan el mismo formato. Igual en este caso: tienes la imagen `144923.jpeg`, si intentas acceder a `144923.jpg` vas a recibir algún error.

Comment: Y si crees que es correcto y que es un problema de configuración de CakePHP o del servidor, entonces tienes que añadir la información de configuración a la pregunta para que podamos ver dónde podría estar el problema.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro gracais por tu respuesta, comprobé lo que dices del formato en un html vacio y efectivamente es como dices, el problema es que la imagen viene desde cake con el formato, no se lo doy yo al momento de mostrarla, y tampoco se donde puede estar el problema de configuración. de todas formas con lo que me dijiste del formato tengo para probar otras cosas, gracias por tus respuestas.